# Firestore addSnapshotListener not being called if View Controller is not shown (back stack of Navigation Controller)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to understand how to make `addSnapshotListener` receive updates even if the View Controller is not being shown.

Let's say I call `addSnapshotListener` on ViewController A and then after some time I go to View Controller B.

In ViewController B, I add some data to a collection that `addSnapshotListener` of ViewController A is listening to. It seems however, that after coming back to ViewController A from ViewController B, the new element is not queried.

I considered calling `addSnapshotListener` to `viewDidAppear` of ViewController A so that it would be updated but wouldn't that require me to remove all listeners before? Isn't there a better solution?

Comment: If the view is not being shown, do you really need it to be aware of changes to the data? You could add the listener in `viewWillAppear` then detach it in `viewDidDisappear`?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't remove the listener when the viewcontroller A disappears, then the listener should get called when you make changes on a viewController pushed on top of the stack.  I've gotten this to work. In the listener code, be sure to check that it's not from cache because sometimes it will call multiple times. Also you can check for document changes using this code.

```
snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
        if (diff.type == .added) {
            print("New city: \(diff.document.data())")
        }
        if (diff.type == .modified) {
            print("Modified city: \(diff.document.data())")
        }
        if (diff.type == .removed) {
            print("Removed city: \(diff.document.data())")
        }
    }
```